# SQL суммировать данные из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, select, zabbix, grafana

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли получить сумму SUM(t.value) по этим данным из базы заббикса? Это айтемы с разных устройств, которые я опрашиваю с одинаковым промежутком, в графане пытаюсь построить суммированный график, один, вместо двух. Данные t.value - просто целые значения. Можно ли сделать из двух запросов один?

```
select t.value as Данные1, t.clock as time 
from hosts h, items i,history_uint t
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='112233' and t.itemid = '0112233'
```

```
select t.value as Данные2, t.clock as time
from hosts h, items i, history_uint t 
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='223344'   and t.itemid = '0223344'
```

Answer (score 0):

Если просто объединить, то

```
select t.value as Данные, t.clock as time 
from hosts h, items i,history_uint t
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='112233' and t.itemid = '0112233'
  union all
select t.value as Данные, t.clock as time
from hosts h, items i, history_uint t 
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='223344'   and t.itemid = '0223344'
```

Если все таки требуется сумма, например `Данные2` это количество, которое можно сложить, то

```
select
  sum(g.data) as Данные, g.time
from (
select t.value as data, t.clock as time 
from hosts h, items i,history_uint t
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='112233' and t.itemid = '0112233'
  union all
elect t.value as data, t.clock as time
from hosts h, items i, history_uint t 
where i.hostid=h.hostid and t.itemid=i.itemid and i.hostid='223344'   and t.itemid = '0223344') g
group by g.time
```

В этом случае в обоих запросах должны встерчаться строки с одинковым временем, иначе результат будет как в первом варианте.

Для справки: в инструкции `UNION ALL` имена полей называются по первому запросу.